# Save additional field using Mongoose Hook

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I would like to save the lower cased version of my `name` field so that I can perform efficient case insensitive searches on the name field. Since I am working with an external API I also store the unmodified response object into my database.

**My question:**

How can I save the lower cased version of my `name` field without modifying the API response (I still would like to pass the response object to my model when saving new documents).

**Dummy model:**

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: true,
  },
  name_lowercased: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    index: true,
  }
})
```

I assume it's possible using the `pre('save')` or `post('save')` hooks, but I have no idea how I could modify the to be saved document in the hooks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the pre-save hook to save the lowercase version of the name field:

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    this.name_lowercased = this.name.toLowerCase();
    next();
});
```

Comment: It appears it's not working for me. I think the hook isn't even called, probably because I use upsert? is there another approach?

Comment: I believe the pre-save hook is not called on update methods so you will need to use 'find()' and then update the name property and the 'save()'. This should then run pre-save.

Comment: wouldn't it be better to do this 'post' in case the field doesn't exist yet? I guess it depends if the object property is already set before this gets hooked